# AWS: I can connect to postgres RDS database but cannot connect to MySQL RDS database

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have one device ,one is my home laptop, one is my pc from work,i trying to connect to RDS database with my laptop from home,it can connect to both postgres RDS and mysql
But with my pc from work,i try everything from Edit inbound rules,set to my local ip,or 0000/0,..
but it just can only connect to postgres database RDS,can not connect with MySQL database RDS, help me

> Security page
>
> Active
> Publicly accessible
> Yes
> Certificate authority
> rds-ca-2019
> Certificate authority date
> August 23, 2024, 12:08 (UTC±12:08)
>
> Connect with MySQL
> Connection Error
> Error invoking remote method 'DB_CONNECT': Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
>
> Connect with PostgresSQL
> Connection Test
> Successfully connected

my bound rules
[image]

Comment: Ask your IT department whether they are blocking outbound TCP/3306.

Comment: You also have Network Access Control List what you can also check

Comment: I change the post to 3333,it notworking bro

Comment: i have change port to 5436 and it complete work,tks for help bro,port start with 3xxx might have been block for some reason.tks for help